# How would I go about making an If Then Statement with a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an If statement where if the person selects English as there Language of choice then the next section of the form will become visible, if they don't select English then the form will close.

Here's the code I have

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString = "English" Then
        Button1.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Any time I hit the button the form closes so the If ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString = "English" Then has to be incorrect but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Try replacing SelectedIndex to SelectedItem.

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is an Integer value, not useful to convert it to a string. Use the  `ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Selecteditem)` method to retrieve the text of the Item selected.

Comment: To help with debugging this, add a breakpoint to the If ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString = "English" Then line and use the watch or the immediate window to see what the value of ListBox1.SelectedIndex actually is.